# In-app Map Directions in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, maps, directions

My iOS app currently launches the Maps app when I need to present the user with driving directions to a given location. This works great, however...

My client has now asked that I provide this functionality in-app (i.e. it doesn't exit the app and launch the Maps app).

Has anyone done this in iOS 6? Can it be done?

The Mono documentation for the various Map Kit classes (MKMapItem, MKDirectionsRequest etc) is non-existant ("Documentation for this section has not yet been entered."), so I'm really struggling.

I'm using Xamarin.iOS, but I can work with obj-c.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MKMapView` does not provide any directions. Thus if you want this in your app you will have to build it your self.

Answer (score 1):

The MapKit API currently does not support what you're looking to accomplish.  And use of undocumented APIs can result in your app being rejected.